# Why image resize in Photoshop generates artifacts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

Left side - the result of downscaling the image from 1800px (height) to 1200px in the Mac OS Image Preview utility.
Right side - the same downscaling in Photoshop (Menu: Image->Image Size...)
You can see significant visual distortions of the photoshop version. How can I avoid this weird behavior?

UPDATE: OK, I've figured out that it happens only when scaling PSD, when I save unscaled image as PNG, and then re-open and downscale it in photoshop, it works perfectly! What's wrong with scaling in PSD?

[image]

Comment: What settings do you use in the Resize Image dialog?

Comment: I tried all interpolation methods, no luck with any...

Comment: Did you save both files in the same format? I’m asking because maybe this is just a problem with the PSD preview. It would also be great if you could provide us with the Original image, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Was the simulated screen a smart object/smart layer?

Answer (score 1):

Resizing is not a good approach,

```
Goto File>Export as Select Format and Resolution plus dpi form there...
```

[image: Photoshop File Export]
You'll get the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it turned out that scaling PSD is totally wrong approach. There is an option "Save for Web" (also "Export As" in CC 2015.5) where target size could be selected.